# Node.js http-server custom error message

Tags: node.js, http, simplehttpserver

I started a node.js http-server - "https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server"
If i type a non existed file in the directory, than I get the browser msg:

```
This localhost page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/foo
Search Google for localhost 8080 foo
HTTP ERROR 404
```

My question:
Can I customise this error msg somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `404.html` file in your `public` directory and put content you want to be shown to that file

**Example**

Command line

`# http-server ./public/`

Content of `./public/404.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>404</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>My custom 404 message</p>
</body>
</html>
```